# I'm wondering if we can prove the following inequality with those ideas.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, inequality, trigonometry

We aim to prove that $\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right)$ $\leq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's assume that $\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right)$ $\geq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Now consider
$\lim_{{y \to \pm\infty}} \tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) \geq \lim_{{y \to \pm\infty}} \left(\tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)\right)$
$\iff \tan(1) \geq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan(1)$
$\iff 0 \geq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right)$
which leads to a contradiction since this is not true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the reverse inequality is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and since it holds the limit inequality, meaning
$\lim_{{y \to \pm\infty}} \tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) \leq \lim_{{y \to \pm\infty}} \left(\tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)\right)$
$\iff \tan(1) \leq \tan(1) + \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) \iff 0 \leq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right)$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) \leq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

If that's not the case, would the iterated limit prove the statement? Maybe the iterated limits from x->inf, y->-inf, then x->-inf, y->inf, then the same variations with y->+/-inf in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flaw in your reasoning.

You first showed that

$$\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) \geq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)\quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$

lead to a contradiction by using a limits based argument. If the inequality above does not hold for all $x,y$, then the correct deduction to make is that there are specific values of $x,y$ such that the inequality does not hold.

Hence you deduce that

$$ \exists x,y \in \mathbb R : \quad\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) < \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right).$$

In general its incorrect to say

> "(inequality holds for all $x$) leads to contradiction" $\implies $ "reverse inequality is true for all $x$"

Instead you should have

> "(inequality holds for all $x$) leads to contradiction" $\implies$ " There exists a value of $x$ such that the reverse inequality is true.

---

In fact this flaw is also present at the start of the answer. Indeed you are trying to prove that

$$\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) \leq \tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right)\quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$

So if you want to prove this by contradiction then your starting point should be assuming that we have

$$ \exists x,y \in \mathbb R : \quad\tan\left(\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\right) >\tan\left(\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\right).$$

This is not practical to work with if you want to use limits as you did.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Would you give me any advise on how to prove that or answer if I can prove it with that logic - the limit based argument?

Comment: @impact21 I don't think that method would work here. The issue is that the initial statement u are trying to prove is of the form "$\forall x,y ... \leq ... $ this means that taking the oposite statement (in order to find a contradiction) would give  something of the form $\exists x, y : ... > ... $ where you would not be able to take limits.